# set cursor position in Outlook AddIn using word editor range.select() new mail

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-addin

My code:

```
 public void inspectors_NewInspector(Inspector _Inspector)
    {
        try
        { 
            if (_Inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem)
            {
                MailItem myMailItem = (MailItem)_Inspector.CurrentItem;
                myMailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><table><tr><td>cursor</td></tr></table></html>";
                Inspector insp = myMailItem.GetInspector;
                insp.Activate();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find uiFind = insp.WordEditor.Range().Find;
                uiFind.Text = "cursor";
                while (uiFind.Execute())
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = uiFind.Parent;
                    rng.Select();
                    rng.Text = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

It is working for reply and forward to set the cursor position but i'm getting an exception like the screenshot below when new mail is selected. Anyone have any suggestion for getting rid of this error??

[image]

Comment: At what time are you calling the above code? Which event?

Comment: Maybe the inspector does not exist at that time, because the error seems to be happening at myMailItem.GetInspector. I expect that when you Reply/Forward it does not open a new inspector window, but just creates new email within the main Outlook Explorer window. Can you include the whole method code in your question?

Comment: If the Inspector is available as a parameter to the method, why are you getting the inspector again by using GetInspector?

Comment: I have tried that too still got error....

Answer (score 0):

Word editor is not fully initialized by the time `NewIsnpector` is called. Wait for the `Inspector.Activate` event to fire. Keep in mind that it fires multiple times.